# Default value at the same time possibility seding whole object item with ngrepeat to function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass parameter to function changeBoard whole variable item but If i dont set value="item._id" i can't have default value. If I set i can only pass item._id.

Can someone help me how can I pass whole parametere item at the same time have default selected?

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/LOjvLL?editors=1111

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
```

**template html**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="select">

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedBoard" ng-change="changeBoard(selectedBoard)">
     <option ng-repeat="item in arrayItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>   
 </select>

</div>
```

**controller**

```
  var app = angular.module('test', []);


app.controller('select', $scope=>{
  $scope.arrayItems = [
    {'id': '133', 'name':'first', 'lists':[{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]},
    {'id': '134', 'name':'second', 'lists':[{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]},
    {'id': '135', 'name':'third', 'lists':[{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]},
    {'id': '136', 'name':'fourth', 'lists':[{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]}
  ];

  $scope.selectedBoard = '134';

  $scope.changeBoard = (selectedBoard) => {
    console.log(selectedBoard)
  }
});
```

Comment: You want to have a default value? Or want `ng-model` to equal `selectedBoard` model? Or want to print out the model being changed, the object in `$scope.arrayItems`? Please clarify.

Comment: I want have selected in select value by id and at the same time I want have possibility after change position in select automatically I want send {{item}} from ng-repeat to function. You understand??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript function `.filter()`. It's kind of like an SQL `WHERE` statement, but for Javascript arrays. It'll just filter out anything based on the function given for it.

In my example, you can remove the pass of `selectedBoard` to the function call in your `ng-change` method. Since you are already binding to the model `$scope.selectedBoard`.

```js
! function() {

  var app = angular.module('test', []);

  var select = function($scope) {
    $scope.arrayItems = [{
        'id': '133',
        'name': 'first',
        'lists': [{
          'name': 1
        }, {
          'name': 2
        }]
      },
      {
        'id': '134',
        'name': 'second',
        'lists': [{
          'name': 1
        }, {
          'name': 2
        }]
      },
      {
        'id': '135',
        'name': 'third',
        'lists': [{
          'name': 1
        }, {
          'name': 2
        }]
      },
      {
        'id': '136',
        'name': 'fourth',
        'lists': [{
          'name': 1
        }, {
          'name': 2
        }]
      }
    ];

    $scope.selectedBoard = '';

    $scope.changeBoard = () => {
      var obj = $scope.arrayItems.filter(item => item.id == $scope.selectedBoard);
      // var obj = $scope.arrayItems.filter(function(item) { // Can also be written as this
      //   return item.id == $scope.selectedBoard;
      // });
      console.log(obj);
    }
  };

  app.controller("select", ["$scope", select]);
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="select">

  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedBoard" ng-change="changeBoard()">
     <option ng-repeat="item in arrayItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>   
 </select>

</div>
```